# What does the number 4-88 mean in "Polyvinylalcohol 4-88"?

Tags: nomenclature, polymers

Polyvinylalcohol is sold in different forms, one of those is **4-88**.

What does that number mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value $\bf{4-88}$ can be described as follows:

> $\bf{4}$: This represents the viscosity (in $\pu{mPa s}$) of a $4\%$ solution in water at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$. This value is *somewhat* proportional to the molecular weight of the polymer chain.
>
> $\bf{88}$: This represents the percentage of moles of acetate ester that were hydrolyzed, since polyvinyl alcohol [is manufactured by hydrolysis of polyvinyl acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinyl_alcohol#Preparation). This means that it is an indicator of its purity.

Source: you can check [the catalogue at Sigma-Aldrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/search?term=9002-89-5&interface=CAS%20No.&N=0&mode=partialmax&lang=es&region=AR&focus=product) (*Mowiol* is a brand name for PVA) and see how those numbers correlate to those parameters.